# Does parseInt change the way jQuery selectors work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, parseint

We are using the following to dynamically change an element's id:

```
$('.next').attr('id','next'+parseInt(Number(id_next)-1));
```

For example, `#next1` becomes `#next0`.

After changing the id, jQuery is no longer able to find the id `#next0`:

```
if($('#next0').length>0){
    $('.previous').css({'visibility' : 'visible'});
    $('.next').css({'visibility' : 'hidden'});
}
```

Is `parseInt` causing a problem here?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: But where/how do you call this snippet: `if($('#next0').length>0)` ??? You have to provide minimalistic sample which replicates your issue. BTW, IDs must be unique, your code will fail if more than one element with class `next`

Comment: Without knowing how you get `id_next` we cannot answer this.  You shouldn't be using `attr("id")` - just use `$(".next")[0].id`.  Also, `parseInt()` isn't jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No parseInt is not causing a problem here.

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate that the code works:
http://jsfiddle.net/sZXJ8/

HTML:

```
<div class="next" id="next1"></div>
```

JS:

```
var id_next = 1;
$('.next').attr('id','next'+parseInt(Number(id_next)-1), 10); // Always include a radix when using parseInt
alert($('#next0').length);
```

Your problem is elsewhere.